# In proc tabulate: access multiple variable values at once

Tags: sas

I want to use `proc tabulate` to display the proportions/ total count of some variables conditioned on their values - if I only want to access one variable at once I was able to achieve this by setting a specific format (please check the **MWE**). However, if I want to access two variables at once (like `score_1 >= x OR score_2 >=y`) I get nowhere.

**MWE:**

```
data have;
input score_1 score_2;
datalines;
2 7
4 4
7 2
;

proc format;
value cut_fmt 
    low - 2 = 'non-critical'
    3 - high = 'critical'
    ;
run;

proc tabulate data = have missing;
format score_1 score_2 cut_fmt.;
class score_1 score_2; 
keylabel N = ' ' ColPCTN = '%' all = 'Total'; 
table score_1 * N score_2 * N, all;
run;
```

[image: output]

I now would like to have an extra row where it says:

```
score_1 OR score_2   
non-critical         0
critical             3
```

Is there a way to achieve this in `proc tabulate` (this shouldn't be possible with a format statement I guess) or would I need to create a new variable before and just use this one then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new variable and add it to the `table` statement.
You will also need `classdata` to ensure `0` counts are presented.

Example:

```
data have;
  input score_1 score_2;
  worst_case = max(score_1, score_2);
  label worst_case = 'score_1 or score_2';
datalines;
2 7
4 4
7 2
;

proc format;
  value cut_fmt 
    low - 2 = 'non-critical'
    3 - high = 'critical'
    ;

data combinations;
  score_1 = 2; 
  score_2 = 2; 
  worst_case = 2; output;
  score_1 = 3; 
  score_2 = 3; 
  worst_case = 3; output;
run;

options missing='0';

proc tabulate data = have classdata=combinations;
  class score_1 score_2 worst_case;
  format score_1 score_2 worst_case cut_fmt.;

  keylabel N = ' ' ColPCTN = '%' all = 'Total'; 

  table score_1 score_2 worst_case, all;
run;

options missing='.';
```

Comment: Thanks! I almost thought so. BTW, nice idea with the ``classdata`` approach. I was trying a different angle with ``preloadfmt missing`` options to the ``class statement`` and ``printmiss misstext='0' `` to the ``table statement`` which yields the same. Will definitely look into your approach!